# How to create Sub Menus in Joomla 3.4?

Tags: joomla, web, development-environment

I am just building out a Personal Portfolio Site using Joomla Platform under TemplateToaster Tool and want to know how to create submenus.I want to add a single Menu in Navigation Bar and want to add 3 submenus under the main menu.
Can anyone help me out of it.Any Joomla User ?

Comment: Check this -http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-submenus-in-joomla-content-managemen.html

Comment: Really, have you even tried Googling this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating menu items that have a "Parent Item" that is a menu item in your main menu. Note that your menu template must support nesting in order for these submenus to appear properly (most Joomla menu templates support nesting).